# 'qualtRics' R package API call returns "port 443: Connection refused". What am I missing?

Tags: r, api, curl, qualtrics, ropensci

Good afternoon!

I'm a self-taught R developer so I might not be using the correct jargon, but please bear with me.

I have written a script to clean and process data which has been manually exported from Qualtrics, however I would like to further automate my data process workflow by tapping directly into the Qualtrics API. I am attempting to use the qualtRics package to handle the API call, but when I execute the function I get a return of port 443: Connection refused. I have yet to find a workable solution for this. I have followed the standard workflow Code below:

```
#Save API Key and Base URL as environment variables
qualtrics_api_credentials(
 api_key = "<API_KEY>",
 base_url = "<BASE_URL>",
 overwrite = TRUE,
 install = TRUE
)

#Refresh environment
readRenviron("~/.Renviron")

#Pull list of surveys
Surveys <- all_surveys()

#Fetch survey data from Survey based on Survey ID
SurveyData <- fetch_survey("Survey_ID",
                           last_response = NULL,
                           start_date = "2019-11-18",
                           end_date = NULL,
                           unanswer_recode = NULL,
                           limit = NULL,
                           include_questions = NULL,
                           save_dir = NULL,
                           force_request = FALSE,
                           verbose = TRUE,
                           label = TRUE,
                           convert = TRUE,
                           import_id = FALSE,
                           local_time = FALSE)
```

For both the all_surveys() and fetch_survey() functions, if I use https:// I get a return of:

"Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
    Failed to connect to  port 443: Connection refused"

and if I use http:// a return of:

"Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
   Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused"

Is there a workaround or a different approach I can take to pull Qualtrics survey data into a data frame via the API?

Best regards

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall and/or on a corporate VPN when you're connecting?

Comment: Ah, yes I am. I hadn't considered that as a unit in my company has connected via the API for some scripting purposes, though not through R. What would you recommend?

Comment: for starters, I'd test whether a simple https request to a public webpage (i.e. not an API call) will go through: httr::GET('https://cran.r-project.org/faqs.html').  If that doesn't return a page, you should reach out to sysadmins at your company.  They may give you proxy settings you can configure yourself (a la the instructions here:  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy).  Or they might configure something on their side of things that takes care of the problem for you.

Comment: The GET request to the cran repository returned the same result. I submitted a ticket to our sysadmins...now we play the waiting game. Thanks for the input! I don't know that I could have figured that out!